# Moving Image is lagging on Canvas with Keydown

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, keydown

So I'm trying to use keydown and keyup to make an image move across the screen using the arrow keys. Well it works but it's extremely laggy. I was wondering if there was a way to make it less laggy. Here is my code:

```
var keys = {};

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);


$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}).keyup(function(e) {

   move(e.keyCode);

    if (keys[38] && keys[37]) {
       kirbyObject.y -=50;
       kirbyObject.x -=50;


    }else if(keys[38] && keys[39]){

      kirbyObject.y -=50;
      kirbyObject.x +=50;


    }else if(keys[40] && keys[39]){

      kirbyObject.y +=50;
      kirbyObject.x +=50;


    }else if(keys[40] && keys[37]){

      kirbyObject.y +=50;
      kirbyObject.x -=50;


    }
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});







var kirbyReady = false;
var kirby = new Image();
kirby.onLoad = function() {
  kirbyReady = true;
};
kirbyObject = {};
kirby.src = "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/spritechronicles/images/5/5c/Kirby.png/revision/latest?cb=20101010225540";

kirbyObject.x = 300;
kirbyObject.y = 300;

var upKey = 38;
var downKey = 40;
var leftKey = 37;
var rightKey = 39;


var move = function(key) {

  if (key == upKey) {
    kirbyObject.y -= 50;
  }else if(key == downKey){

    kirbyObject.y +=50;
    //console.log("down");
        console.log(kirbyObject.y);


  }else if(key == leftKey){

    kirbyObject.x -=50;
  }else if(key == rightKey ){

    kirbyObject.x +=50;
  }
  // MORE DIRECTIONS!!!
};


var render = function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(kirby, kirbyObject.x, kirbyObject.y);
};

var main = function() {

  render();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

main();
```

Comment: I tested your code quickly, and I want to warn you about the fact that pressing two perpendicular arrow (e.g. down & left) at the same time doubles the sprite speed. And what do you mean by "laggy" ? For me, it's moving the sprite on the key up event.

Comment: @Seblor might have your answer. Your code does move the sprite, but the movement occurs on `keyup`. Try moving the sprite on keydown -- which is more usual since holding keydown will generate multiple events and therefore multiple movements.

Comment: @markE keydown event has a delay before firing again, it will always look laggy. The solution is to use keydown as a trigger to start moving, and keyup as the one to stop it.

Comment: @Kaiido. Yes, keydown triggers movement, maybe rAF to throttle movement at a specified rate and keyup to end movement. That sounds better. I really need to stop answering questions at 2am. zzzzzz!